# Laravel notification is broadcasted when the queue connection is set to database, but not when set to redis

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing this weird issue, I have a notification `App\Notifications\SomethingHappened`.

I am using laravel-websockets package. I have my queue connection set to database and my notification class which implements `ShouldQueue` interface, has the following `to*` methods: `toArray()`, `toMail()` and another custom channel.

Also, the `via()` method has these channels: `database`, `broadcast` and conditionally (if the user has email), `mail`.

My broadcast route in `channels.php` looks like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

I do not have a `toBroadcast()` method since the documentation suggested that,

> [The toArray method is also used by the broadcast channel to determine which data to broadcast to your JavaScript client](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications).

When I have my queue connection set to `database`, the notification is broadcasted to the client properly. Here is the log:

```
[2019-04-18 09:29:42][1] Processing: App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:29:46][1] Processed:  App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:29:46][2] Processing: App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:29:47][2] Processed:  App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:29:47][3] Processing: App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:29:47][3] Processed:  App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:29:47][4] Processing: App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:29:47][4] Processed:  App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:29:47][5] Processing: Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated
[2019-04-18 09:29:47][5] Processed:  Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated
```

Notice the last process. But when I set my queue connection to `redis`, this is what I get:

```
[2019-04-18 09:24:25][3] Processing: App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:24:25][3] Processed:  App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:24:25][4] Processing: App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:24:26][4] Processed:  App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:24:25][1] Processing: App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:24:25][2] Processing: App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:24:27][2] Processed:  App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
[2019-04-18 09:24:28][1] Processed:  App\Notifications\SomethingHappened
```

What mistake did I make?

Comment: Try broadcasting to log.  If the logs show up - then we'll look at the js or the socket/port.  Your browser's js error console may shed some light too.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have Cross Origin Read Block warning in the console. Could that be responsible?

Comment: have you install redis package using composer?

Comment: predis, yes I have.

Comment: have you implement ShouldBroadcast Interface in Your Notification class?

Comment: Yes, already mentioned in the question :)

Comment: you mentioned ShouldQueue Interface .

Comment: Oh, my apologies. No I haven't implemented the ShouldBroadcast interface

Comment: please implement ShouldBroadcast Interface in Notification class.

Comment: In that case, what should I return from the `broadcastOn()` method?

Comment: sorry i forgot ShouldBroadcast is for Events. for Notification ShouldQueue is Okay.

Comment: That's what I thought